# Let $X_1,...,X_4\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $\overline{X}_4=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i$. What is $P[\overline{X}_4\geq-\frac{1}{2}]$?

Tags: probability

---

Let $X_1,...,X_4\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $\overline{X}_4=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i$. What is $P[\overline{X}_4\geq-\frac{1}{2}]$?

**My solution:**

I know (according to a theorem) that $\overline{X}_4\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{4})$. Therefore $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}$. And therefore
$$
\frac{\overline{X_4}}{\frac{1}{2}/\sqrt{4}}
=
\frac{\overline{X_4}}{\frac{1}{4}}
=
4\overline{X_4}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$
Therefore
$$
P[\overline{X}_4\geq-\frac{1}{2}]
=
P[4\overline{X}_4\geq-2]
=
1-P[4\overline{X}_4\leq-2]
=
1-\Phi(-2)
=
1-(1-\Phi(2))
=
\Phi(2)
=
0.97725.
$$

**Master solution:** says that the probability is $0.8413$, which is $\Phi(1)$.

**My question:** Have I done an error somewhere? (I can't find it) Or is the master solution wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\bar{X}_4\sim N\left(\bar{μ}=0,\bar{σ}^2=\frac14\right)$ (where $\bar{μ}$ and $\bar{σ}^2$ is just a notation to denote the mean and the variance (or standard deviation) of $\bar X_4$), then $$Z=\frac{\bar X_4-\bar{μ}}{\sqrt{\bar{σ}^2}}=\frac{\bar X_4-0}{\sqrt{\frac14}}=2\bar X_4 \sim N(0,1)$$ and not $4\bar{X}_4\sim N(0,1)$ as you have it. So, your mistake is in the denominator where you had $\frac12 /\sqrt{4}$ instead of $\sqrt{\frac14}$.

Comment: I see, I used the wrong variance! When using the variance of $\overline{X}_n$ I don't need to divide by $\sqrt{n}$. I only need to divide by $\sqrt{n}$ if I use the variance of the $X_i$'s. Thank you!

Comment: @ndrizza Yes, that's it.